# How to animate the camera to point at the part of gltf model on clicking it using threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have used a gltf loader to load a model and added a click function to it. When clicked on a part of the model it should change the camera postition and rotation to focus on the clicked part. Currently the camera changes position and rotation. But its very abrupt. How can I animate the change in position instead of an abrupt change.

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load('perseverance.gltf', function(gltf){
  scene.add(gltf.scene);

  box_model = gltf.scene.getObjectByName( "box" )
  mast_cams = gltf.scene.getObjectByName( "Mastcam_Z_cams" )
  console.log(mast_cams);

    domEvents.addEventListener(mast_cams, 'click', function(event){

        if(!mast_cams_clicked){
            console.log("mast_cams clicked")
            camera.position.set(-1.340 ,2.6 , 2.180);
            camera.rotation.set(-13, -18.40, -3.20);
            controls.update();
            mast_cams_clicked = true;
        }else{
            console.log("Reset")
            controls.reset();
            mast_cams_clicked = false;
        }
        
    })
//   animate();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you are using an animation library like GSAP for this task. Here is a complete example:

```js
let renderer, scene, camera;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.set( 20, 20, 20 );
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );
    
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
    light.position.set( 20,20, 0 );
    scene.add( light );
    
    scene.add( new THREE.AxesHelper( 20 ) );

    const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 12, 8 );
    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
        color: 0x00ffff, 
        flatShading: true,
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.7,
    } );
    
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );
        
    gsap.to( camera.position, {
        duration: 1,
        y: 10,
        onUpdate: () => {
                
            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

        }
    } );
    
}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.3/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.4.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

Notice how the camera looks at the target position when updated. Instead of using `scene.position`, use the target position of the raycast.

BTW: I suggest you disable the controls when the animation starts and enable it again when it is finished. You can use the `onComplete()` to detect the animation's end.

Comment: The camera animation now works But the next issue is that instead of camera pointing at the clicked element camera moves to the top points at the position from above

Comment: I used the position of sphere to specifically point at when animation updates and completes